# div.fixed with 100% width only with css

Tags: html, css

How can I have div.fixed at 100% of the width of its parent .content? ... knowing that all widths will be variable, even .content

more or less what I need is .content with position: relative; div.fixed with the position: absolute; and width: 100%; But fixed at the top if I have a vertical scroll

and if possible without using JavaScript, only with CSS.

I was trying several things but none works, thank you for your time and help

```css
.sidebar {
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .content {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #d5d2ca;
        min-height: 900px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
    }
    .fixed {
        background-color: #aaffaa;
        padding: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: calc(100% - 40px);

    }
    .content p {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="sidebar">
    the sidebar is going to have variable width
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed
    </div>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove width:40% from .content. Also, remove style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;"

Comment: if you want to make the div with `position: absolute` to have 100% of its parent, then we can give the parent `position: relative`. but if the div is `position: fixed` then it will not be contained in its parent. It will **only respect the width of the page and the width we give you.** So if still want a solution then we have to go with `script`.

Comment: Thanks @weBer ... it's the same thing I was thinking ... I came here to see if anyone had any other ideas

Answer (score 1):

100% of .content? That would be

```
width:calc(40% - 40px);
```

Comment: Thank you @Razvan... but .content will have any value, not 40%

Comment: @lecaro ok, so .fixed needs to be 100% of what?

Comment: sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough, I edited the post, can you see if you can help me... please

Answer (score 1):

For your question to be solved, must `width` of `.content` equal with `width` of `.fixed` so, use of:

```
.fixed {
    width: inherit;
    //so .fixed get width 40%
}
```

But,

`.fixed` have `position:fixed`, so `40%` is  relative to the screen's viewport,

and

`.content` is `40%`  relative to his parent[`div` with `width:90%`,(90% relative to body)].

in here ,we have to do something to measure both elements relative to one element.so,do this:

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

<div style="width:100%; margin:5px 70px;">
 of 90% to 100%----^            ^---^-------optional
```

also, use `margin-left:-20px` for remove affect `padding:20px` in `.content`.

```
.fixed {
    margin-left: -20px;
    //more code...
}
```

Nowو you have both elements have `width:40%` relative to same element.

**Note,** *Get Full Page to better see result.*

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #d5d2ca;
    min-height: 900px;
    position: relative;
}

.fixed {
    background-color: #aaffaa;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}

.content p {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; margin:5px 70px;">
    <div class="sidebar">
        the sidebar is going to have variable width
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="fixed">
            Fixed
        </div>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ehsan ... it looks like you're a pro in css ... the thing is I can not put body and html at 100% width without affecting something else ... even the main container  (witdth 90%) I can't touch it ... I think, I'll need to use js ... I modified the post maybe I can give you some other idea ... what do you think ?, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

change that line:

```
<div style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">
```

to

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
```

also add to the class:

```
.fixed {
            width: 100%;
       }
```

and remove `width:40%;` from the `.content`

Comment: I put a value to put something ... but it is not 90%, could be any number, not 100%

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand the problem correctly, but if you want to make the fixed div to have 100% of its parent, then the following should work

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.fixed {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I edited the post, can you see if you have some idea?